# Saving Sharepoint data into SQLite table

Tags: python, list, sharepoint

I'm trying to save data from Multiple Sharepoint Sites into a SQLite DB File. I'm able to access the data using Sharepoint library. But having trouble converting the Sharepoint Lists into Pandas Dataframe & then write into SQLite table. 
I used the below sites for support, here is a snippet of my code
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sharepoint/0.4.1
[Saving SharePoint list with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258482/saving-sharepoint-list-with-python)

I'm not sure if there is a different technique to loop through the Sharepoint List and write into SQL Insert. I'm just a little more comfortable with the Pandas library. Current plan is Sharepoint LIst --> DataFrame --> SQL. How can I solve this problem? 
PS: I'm new to Python and have started using it only last week :)

```
import pandas as pd
# Importing Sharepoint Library
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener
import urllib2
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
# Windows Credentials
username="xxxxx"
password='xxxxxx'

# The sharepoint info
server_url="https://example.com/"
site_url=server_url+"sites/XYZ/"
# list_name='list_name'
# FieldName='Output Field'


passman=urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None,server_url,username,password)
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

# Create and Install the opener
opener=urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# Create a sharepoint object

site=SharePointSite(site_url,opener)
sp_list=site.lists['list_name']
#     print row.id,row.Column1, row.Column2
          TestDictionary=dict({'Column1':'Column1','Column2_x0020_Field2' : 'Column2'})

 df=pd.from_dict(TestDictionary)
 df.to_sql()
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
I used a list to store the SharepointList. Once the list is created then you can easily load into the Data frame.

```
data=[]
for row in sp_list.rows:
  data.append[(Column1,Column2_x0020_Field2)] 
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Column1','Column2'])
```